# yasm: Expected `,' with immediate value

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, yasm

Given the following assembly program:

```
BITS 64
mov rax, 0b111
```

Yasm outputs:

```
error: expected `,'
```

Why does it expect a comma here? NASM happily assembles this.

Comment: Doesn't YASM expect a `b` _suffix_ for binary literals? (i.e. `111b`)

Comment: Yes, I just discovered that! What a weird difference to have versus nasm. Feel free to post this as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the YASM manual:

> 3.5.1. Numeric Constants
>   A numeric constant is simply a number. NASM allows you to specify numbers in a variety of number bases, in a variety of ways: **you can suffix** H, Q or O, and **B for** hex, octal, and **binary**, or you can prefix 0x for hex in the style of C, or you can prefix $ for hex in the style of Borland Pascal. 
>   
>   Some examples:
>           `mov ax,10010011b        ; binary`

The NASM manual adds:

> In addition, current versions of NASM accept the **prefix** 0h for hexadecimal, 0d or 0t for decimal, 0o or 0q for octal, and **0b or 0y for binary**.

TL;DR: While NASM supports both a `b`-suffix and a `0b`-prefix for binary literals, YASM only supports the suffix variant. So `0b111` needs to be written as `111b`.